# MPMoviePlayerViewController videos with transparent background

Tags: ios

I would like to play inside my app a video which has a transparent background. it has a man moving around on a transparent background. The only problem is that the MPMovieePlayer seems to have a black background. How can I make it transparent?

This is the code I tried:

```
-(void)playMovie
{
       NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"syncink movie" ofType:@"m4v"];
       NSLog(@"%@",resourcePath);
       NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath];
       NSLog(@"%@",url);

       MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer;

       moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

       moviePlayer.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
       moviePlayer.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
       [moviePlayer.moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
       [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

       moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(200, 600, 400, 300);

       [moviePlayer.moviePlayer play];

       moviePlayer.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

       for(UIView *aSubView in moviePlayer.view.subviews) 
       {
          aSubView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
       }
}
```

but

> aSubView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

seems to be removing the frame of the player, not the actual background. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `MPMoviePlayerController` here, instead of a `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. The latter is a view controller that presented (typically in a modal fashion).

This way, when you add the moviePlayer.view to your hierarchy as a subview, you will be adding the movie player view itself, rather than a view containing the movie player (which is the flat black screen that you are seeing).

Also, by using `MPMoviePlayerController`, you can simplify `moviePlayer.moviePlayer` in your code everywhere to just `moviePlayer`.